# How to coerce a string-like date to Date object

Tags: r, date, xts

Let you have an object like this:

```
> dput(maturityDate)
"3/6/2018"
```

that is just a text string which represents a date in M/D/YYYY format.

The following command returns:

```
> as.Date(maturityDate)
[1] "0003-06-20"
```

which is clearly not the output I wish.

Any idea how may I coerce it into a `Date` object in the usual format dealt by `xts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
as.Date("3/6/2018",format="%m/%d/%Y")
```